# Abandoning Bootstrap for my own framework

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've been working on an Admin interface for a desktop-first web application. There will be an iOS application for mobile users and if we need browser support on mobile, a mobile-first UI will likely be designed. I've only been working with CSS/JS/HTML for about 30-days, so please forgive any mistakes I make.

to get rolling, I started using Bootstrap, however, I ran into a number of issues and decided to abandon it. I do not require responsiveness in the traditional sense of a grid system and fine tuning my design using a grid model was truly painful.

I discovered on my journey that using @Media, I could adjust the CSS for various elements based on screen resolution and even go so far as to remove an element using width="0" and introduce a new element by turning it's width on. I'm using flexbox for my layout, which I find to be incredibly effective to work with and provides me with solid control over the presentation of my UI.

I plan to eventually convert my admin into a EmberJS app, which give me even more control over when and how elements are displayed.

Although I'm still learning, I've found resources like w2schools.com to be very helpful in adding elements like a sidebar using plain JS and CSS. This keeps my application simple and easy to follow, rather than having to work with a monolith framework.

My question is, is it acceptable to adjust your design based screen size and add and remove elements using a width="0" as the toggle or is there a better way? Also, is it acceptable to adjust your layout overall using @Media versus a grid?

I'd like to eventually turn my app into a native Windows app using Electron so I'd like to not make any bad choices that will cause me problems later.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you use `width: 0` instead of (for example) `display: block`?

Comment: @Media is the same system of any framework grid like bootstrap.... your question is off-topic for SO. **Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.**

Comment: Word to the wise: don't take about 10 paragraphs to get to the point when one will do - this is really wordy. Keep it concise or people won't bother reading. Also, honestly - rolling your own is a good learning experience but all of your questions can be solved by - you guess it - using a decent pre-rolled solution. If bootstrap is too heavy-handed for you, look for something well used but lighter.

Comment: media queries vs grid doesn't really make sense, they are solutions to different problems

Comment: I think you're confusing a few concepts here. A grid system isn't opposed to media queries - it just provides a standardized way to arrange and manage content. Bootstrap's own grid system uses media queries to change its layout according to screen width, so...not sure how to answer your last question. Yes, I guess? And there's nothing wrong with completely hiding elements for different viewport sizes - Bootstrap uses `display:none` for that (you may want to as well). All in all, sounds like you could benefit from reading some more books/online resources first, before proceeding.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I will experiment with dispaly:none rather than width=0. I guess it was breaking the design into 12 quadrants that I found difficult to achieve the design I was looking for. I want complete control of widths down to the pixel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it acceptable to adjust your design based screen size and add and
>   remove elements using a width="0" as the toggle or is there a better
>   way

there is a better way:
use css `display: none` property to hide and show elements but this also removes the space occupied by elements.

If you just need to set visibility off then use `visibility: hidden`

> is it acceptable to adjust your layout overall using @Media versus a grid

yes its fine to use `@media` queries. But using bootstrap grid system is pretty easy and it can also handle cross browser issues which otherwise you would have to handle manually.